# Comparing the order of three arrays with the same elements

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have three arrays.  The arrays all have the same size and contain the same elements.  However, the three arrays must not be in the same order.  How do I verify that the elements are not in the same order?

Here's how I've implemented it:

```
    all_elements_equal = true
    array1.zip(array2, array3) do |first, second, third|
        if first != second && second != third && first != third
            all_elements_equal = false
        end
    end
```

If all_elements_equal is false, presumably the arrays are not in the same order.  However, there is a possibility that this will not be the case if only one of the arrays is different and the other two are identical.

So, my question is, how do I make the test stronger, and is there a more elegant way of implementing the code?  Full disclosure: I am new to Ruby.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
array1 == array2 || array1 == array3 || array2 == array3
```

Comment: +1 - Just tested this with a simple example and the logic does indeed work as expected.

Comment: This worked.  Turns out the solution was simpler than I thought it would be!

Comment: something slightly fancier (not necessarily better): `[array1, array2, array3].combination(2).all? { |a, b| a != b }`

Answer (score 1):

In general, if you have array `arr` of N such arrays, you can just check if there are any duplicates there:

```
arr.length == arr.uniq.length
```

because, for example:

```
[[1,2,3],[2,3,1],[1,2,3]].uniq
#=> [[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 1]]
[[1,2,3],[2,3,1],[2,1,3]].uniq
#=> [[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 1], [2, 1, 3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Ruby, but I think you need to inverse your logic.

```
anyElementEqual=false
do
    if first==second || first==third || second==third
        anyElementEqual=true
end
etc.
```